# When does 'aria-describedby' return null value

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers-3

When i tried to get DOM element generated by Bootrstrap, it is returning as null.

```
var x= document.getElementById(element.getAttribute('aria-describedby'));
```

x is returning null value.I was trying this for popover in openlayers. Why is it so?

Comment: This is because the element was not created the moment you try to get it. Show some more code so we can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getElementById` method returns *null* if no element has been found with that ID. Note that the value **is** case-sensitive. So the value of `aria-describedby` needs to have the same case as the ID value on the corresponding element. Lastly, make sure this code runs *after* the desired element (that element having the targeted id value) has already been added to the DOM.